# Limits of entire functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, asymptotics

Given an entire function $f \left(x \right)$, which entire function $g \left(x \right)$ is asymptotic to $f \left(x \right)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and asymptotic to $1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?
When I say asymptotic, I mean that the limit of their quotient is equal to $1$.

We assume that $x$ stays always positive.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by *asymptotic*, but how about

$$g(x) = f(x)-f(0)+1\:?$$

(I.e. change the $x^0$ coefficient in the Maclaurin series of $f$ to $1$.)